# Disk Management is not working properly

Tags: partitioning, disk-space

My Windows 7 computer's Disk Management is not working properly. I can shrink the D: drive which is not primary partition, the unallocated space comes out. I then tried to create a new simple volume.

After the wizard Disk Management says:

> The Disk Management console is not up to date, please refresh.

I pressed the refresh button and the unallocated space remained the same amount. There is no new volume.

How can I shrink drive C: and extend it to drive D:? If I try to do this it will say:

> The maximum number of partition has reached.

I think it may be because the C: drive is the primary boot drive.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of disk management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 4 partitions already then that's the limit.

Otherwise if you're still struggling try and use a 3rd party tool, such as GParted, while your current OS isn't running.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-gparted-to-resize-your-windows-vista-partition/